# Why is my .htaccess not working when uploaded to a Pantheon server?

Tags: .htaccess

My drupal site has a `.htaccess` file on which I am redirecting the page without changing the URL.

It's working fine on local server & other servers but when I upload the files & databases to pantheon server It will not redirect the page saying *404 not found*. I placed `.htaccess` at the root of code folder, I tried placing it in server root folder, sites/ folder & themes/ folder but nothing works for me.

Does anybody know what is the correct placement of `.htaccess` in a Drupal site on Pantheon? And why my `.htaccess` is not working on Pantheon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Pantheon servers use [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/), and they don't enable .htaccess support.

You should contact them directly to discuss your options (if you're lucky and/or have a high enough subscription they'll probably add some custom rules to the nginx conf for you).

Comment: Oh man its not fair. They say use settings.php to use any redirects etc. Can you tell me how I can redirect silently using settings.php.

Comment: Simple redirect using setting.php working fine but its not silently redirect i.e. it changes the URL also.

Comment: A redirect is never transparent, it'll always take you somewhere else (by design) - what you're looking for is a rewrite, and that is more often than not done at the server level. You could theoretically hack something together using `$_SERVER` vars to change the internal path before Drupal is even bootstrapped, but exactly how you accomplish it depends on a bunch of things. I'd advise opening a ticket with Pantheon and asking them to let you inject rules into their server conf. Drupal also has https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7

Comment: I have opened the ticket & get the following comment on that:
We have an optimized and standardized nginx configuration that is integral to the platform, so we can’t make changes for individual sites.

I think you may need to find an alternative way of achieving this.

Comment: That's a shame. They've offered to do it for me in the past, but that was on an enterprise package. The server setup may be different for those accounts